# Remove duplicate words in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel and have a problem that I cannot solve.

I have data in a cell that contains duplicates, e.g.:

```
"Abraham/Beta/Abraham/Charlie"
```

I would like to remove the second repeats to "Beta/Charlie"

Does anyone have shortcut how to do this quickly? Currently, I'm going through each and every cell manually and it's a lot of work. Thanks.

Comment: In your example should the result be `Abraham/Beta/Charlie` or `Beta/Charlie`?

Comment: Multiple ways to accomplish this. What have you tried?

Comment: i want the result "Beta/Charlie". @AlexP I had tried install KU Tools and select the duplicate and delete it, but it will be manual for the entire project. i need it to be automate when i had thousands data like that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution.

```
Sub DeDupe()
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, arr As Variant, rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cl In rng
        arr = Split(cl, "/")

        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                If Not dict.Exists(arr(i)) Then
                    dict.Add arr(i), arr(i)
                End If
            Next i

        cl.Offset(0, 1) = Join(dict.Items, "/")        
    Next cl    
End Sub
```

This works by splitting the data on `/` and then creating a dictionary of unique values which are then joined together to create the de-duplicated output.

Notes:

1. You need a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. See `Tools > References ...`
2. Here it is assumed your data are in `A1:A10` and you want the output in `B1:B10`

Comment: valid answer and solid instruction +1)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution via `Filter` function**

In addition to @Alex P 's valid answer and just for the sake of the art, I demonstrate an approach via repetitive **filtering** a datafield array allowing a faster loop (without using a dictionary):

**Example code**

```
Sub DelDupes()
  Dim i&, ii&, rng As Range
  Dim v, arr                                ' Variant arrays
' [0] define data source range (omitting assumed title in 1st row)
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A2:A10")
' [1] get 2-dim datafield array
  v = rng                                   ' create datafield array
' [2] loop through variant datafield array v
  For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
      arr = Split(v(i, 1), "/")             ' create array from element i
    ' [3] check each string in arr
      For ii = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
          If ii > UBound(arr) Then Exit For ' escape condition
        ' more than 2 findings of current search string...
          If UBound(Filter(arr, arr(ii), , vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
            ' redefine array excluding found duplicates (i.e. make it smaller)
              arr = Filter(arr, arr(ii), False, vbTextCompare)
              ii = ii - 1                   ' reduce string counter
          End If
       Next ii
     ' [4] remember row result
       v(i, 1) = Join(arr, "/")
  Next i
' [5] write adapted data back to sheet (e.g. into next column via offset 1)
  rng.Offset(0, 1) = v
End Sub
```

**Caveat**

This solution also counts found string *portions* as duplicate strings!

Comment: i tried to use this code but ihad an error "  For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)" it says type missmatch.. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: THANKS IT WORKS THIS THREAD IS SOLVED THANKYOU SO MUCH :*